# require() not running synchronously?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm trying to load a module I created, and when it's loaded use some of it's methods. But it seems the code after the `require` gets executed before the `require` actually finishes.

Here is some code :

```
console.log(db);
var db = require('../../models')(true, v);
console.log(db);
```

Both `console.log` output `undefined`.

Here is the code inside `../../models` :

```
module.exports = function(sync, v) {
  if(sync === true && typeof v !== 'undefined') {
    var db = null;
    async.series([function(callback) {
      require('../lib/db_connect.js').connect(require('../lib/config.js').vars.db, function(res) {
        db = res;
        callback();
      });
    }], function() {
      return loadModels(db, v).models; // this returns the db instance with the models loaded
    });
  } else { /* other stuff */ }
});
```

However, I see the connection debug popping in the console some time after (so it gets loaded, just not synchronous). What am I doing wrong? `async.series` should return only when everything is finished? And most of all, not return undefined?

Comment: Your `.connect` call is asynchronous. What are you expecting to be synchronous? Your `return loadModels(db, v).models` line makes no sense because returning in the result callback of `async.series` doesn't return to anywhere.

Comment: You're right. However, if I dig a little more in my modules I see that there are many other async functions being executed. Is there a way to achieve my db connection synchronously other than passing a `sync` parameters all the way up to all the calls? Like, wait for all the async stuff to finish and then return something to the `require`?

Comment: Create a module that has an instance of EventEmmiter with global application events you'll want and manage the DB setup by emitting an event once DB setup operations are complete?